# Prove the limit of $(x+y)/(x^2+y^2)$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ does not exist

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How to prove that the limit of
$$
\frac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}
$$
as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ does not exist?

I tried with $y = x$ , $x = 0$ , $y = 0$, which gives the limit of negative infinity and positive infinity, Somehow, I feel It's not correct.  Any better ways?

Comment: That's all you need actually. You should be ok I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very much correct. You've shown that close to $(0,0)$, the value of $\frac{x+y}{x^2 + y^2}$ does not approach one specific value. Not even $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: Can I prove like this ? If x = 0 , which leaves 1/y , as y approaches to 0 from the left , we get negative infinity , from the right , we get postive infinity. −∞ not equal +∞.  Thank you !

Comment: @Snailwalker Yeah, that's enough to prove that the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=y $ then we get the expression $1/x $ which is unbounded near  $(0,0) $. Hence the limit does  not exist